# Running some XP patches via command line using /quiet keeps update in memory

Tags: windows, windows-xp, command-line, cmd.exe

Whenever I run some XP patches using /quiet option they remain in memory forever. If I use /passive it works. If I don't use any switches it works.

Answer (score 0):

> Whenever I run some XP patches using /quiet option they remain in memory forever.

The key word in your problem is `some`.

What’s happening is that some updates require input from the user and thus cannot be automated. Some updates don’t support being run with `/quit` because then they end waiting for you to click a button or accept an EULA or something, but without the dialog being shown, you cannot do it, so it just sits there, invisibly waiting.

The problem is that the installer framework handles those switches, so it allows them even if it shouldn’t be used with that specific update. If you install through Windows Update, it will skip that switch on updates that require input, but if you do it manually, then you end up with this problem.